# TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-bootstrap

I've got a new react project with webpack and am trying to add "react-bootstrap" to it and render an Alert as a test.

So I've done:

```
npm install react-bootstrap --save
```

And have verified the files are there. In my main tsx file I have:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
...
<Alert variant='success'>Success Alert</Alert>
```

When I run npm start to kick my server up, it renders the page with a success alert on it absolutely fine, but has the webpack error splash with the following error:

```
[tsl] ERROR in ....\src\client-react\components\Header.tsx(9,23)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap'.
```

Even though the alert is being properly displayed underneath (and if I hack the css to make the display: none on the error splash it seems absolutely fine underneath?

I *think* this is down to there not being any @types for the react-bootstrap package (the @types/react-bootstrap is for an older version as they have apparently rolled the types into the main package) but am not sure how to fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the version of `react-bootstrap`?

Comment: It's the latest from npm: "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",

Comment: Add to your project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-bootstrap

Comment: @Oleg I've tried that, but it doesn't work, as their docs say: "This library is intended for releases of react-bootstrap prior to v1.0.0, e.g. v0.32.4." Whereas I'm using v1.0.0-beta.12

Comment: You can add to tsconfig.json : skipLibCheck:true

Answer (score 2):

I was going through examples provided in [`react-bootstrap`](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-bootstrap/code-sandbox-examples/tree/master/basic-ts) using Typescript. The approach here is to import package in `index.tsx` as:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

I hope you have `react-app-env.d.ts` file to reference `react-scripts` types, which is automatically generated if not create one and add

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

So in your **Hello.tsx**,
You can import `Alert` from `react-bootstrap` as:

```
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix it - I think this is more of a webpack config issue somewhere than an issue with the react-bootstrap module itself

Comment: Maybe, this solution handles the unavailability of any `@types` for the new `react-bootstrap` package.

Comment: Can you share your package.json and some more error logs?